# ¿Cuál es el análisis gramatical de "Hay pan"?

Tags: gramática

¿Cuál es el análisis gramatical de la siguiente oración? ¿Qué tipo de oración es?
Es decir, ¿qué funcion gramatical cumplen cada una de las siguientes palabras?:

> Hay pan.

Estoy buscando la respuesta más precisa, soy todo ojos a posibles interpretaciones, análisis, incluso "nuevas teorías" o "teorías propias"

***Editado***:

Por ejemplo:

Impersonal con complemento directo:
Concuerda con el analisis mas certero a mi modo de ver, pero las oraciones o proposiciones impersonales tienen como caracteristica el verbo en plural. "Tocan el timbre". En este caso debería de ser "Hemos pan" (o "Han pan", si no fuera "Ha pan" la singular). Claramente el verbo "haber" no está usado como auxiliar, y mantiene su significado completo: poseemos pan, tenemos pan.
De más está decir (cosa que no especifíca la RAE al buen approach de CesarGon) es que (y en esto se equivoca a mi entender la RAE, una vez mas) la primera prueba de fuego para analizar un OD es transmutar la oración a voz pasiva (y no el pronombre átono). "Tocan el timbre" por "El timbre es tocado" puede realizarse perfectamente en una impersonal.

Oracion simple con sujeto expreso simple:
Esta es la mas alejada de mis posiciones, sin embargo es viable en algunos aspectos. Hay con el significado de "existir" y lo que existe, es el sujeto, pan. Además concuerda en todos los aspectos, salvo cuando el sujeto cambia de número. "Hay panes". Por lo cual me parece alejada.

También puede cumplir la función de circunstancial, con una mirada un tanto abierta.

Con respecto a la Real Academia Española, por razones que no vienen al caso, sinceramente me parece que la visión que pueden tener deja bastante que desear, la cual en muchos casos es contradictoria u objetable; más allá de que nunca se ha preocupado por realizar lo que su lema propone. Pero es algo personal, prefiero realmente debatir el tema con personas interesadas y obtener nuevas perspectivas de análisis.

Nota:

No es un chiste, juego o test. Tengo tres diferentes respuestas y a las tres les encuentro errores y aciertos. Quiero conocer y aprender cómo se analiza en otros ámbitos fuera del mío. No es una pregunta con trampa.

Comment: hahahahahahahaha, I know the answer, but since it's part of a test I will not answer it :)

Comment: Really no, is not a test. Actually I dont have an answer. Or even worst, I've three different answers.

Comment: Oración Simple enunciativa impersonal atributiva.

Comment: +1 for the excellent question

Comment: As it's worded, it does indeed look like a question taken from a test, or a discussion piece or "puzzle" question--all of which would be off topic. If you have three answers, what additional information are you looking for? If you are trying to resolve problems in the three answers, please post those answers for others to critique.

Comment: Yeah @Flimzy, you have a point on that, I'll post my cases in this week, I'm full of work for these days.

Comment: @user983248 entiendo tu respuesta pero me genera una duda, a que llamas o por que le llamas "atributiva"? No logro entender ese approach y es nuevo para mi. Gracias :)

Comment: @Leandro atributiva esta de mas :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se trata de una oración impersonal. El análisis es el siguiente:

- Hay: verbo impersonal.
- pan: objeto directo.

Ver el Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas sobre [uso impersonal de "haber"](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltConsulta?lema=haber), punto 4; o también [aquí](http://www.asmadrid.org/spanish/depto/gram/Imperson.htm).

Comment: +1 por el link sobre el uso impersonal de "haber"

Comment: si, yo te di +1 (no lo comente) porque el approach es obviamente interesante, y me dio la referencia de la RAE para el ejemplo de "hemos pan". Sin embargo sigo sin poder pasarlo a voz pasiva. En cambio las impersonales las puedo pasar a voz pasiva: Tocan el timbre - El timbre es tocado.

Comment: @Leandro: "Tocan el timbre" no es impersonal, sino que posee un sujeto ("ellos") elíptico. Impersonales son, por ejemplo, "*hay* pan", "*llueve*" o "*es* cierto lo que dices". Ver http://www.asmadrid.org/spanish/depto/gram/Imperson.htm

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo para nada con ese analisis, para mi no existen las falsas impersonales. Si asi fuera, no estarian en plural, nadie dice "toca el timbre". Pero bueno es otra historia...

Comment: @Leandro: No entiendo tu lógica. ¿Puedes explicarla, por favor, o incluir alguna referencia a algún trabajo que la apoye? Gracias.

Comment: CesarGon: me refiero al analisis de "impersonales falsas" en el link, disculpa la mala referencia. Se puede editar un comentario tan viejo?

Answer (score 2):

### Español

Sin duda debe ser un verbo impersonal con un objeto directo.

1. Una frase como "lo hay" apunta claramente a un objeto directo ("lo" no funciona como sujeto)
2. Hay otros verbos impersonales que se usan en singular, como "hace frío", "llueve", etc.

---

### Inglés

Surely it must be an impersonal verb with a direct object.

1. A sentence like 'lo hay' clearly points towards direct object ('lo' doesn't work as subject).
2. There are other impersonal verbs which are used in the singular, like 'hace frío', 'llueve', etc.

Answer (score 1):

En el espanol existen los llamados verbos impersonales, los cuales carecen de sujeto. Ejemplos de estos son llueve, relampaguea, truena, etc.. Estos por lo general se les asignan a la naturaleza, pero intenta darle un sujeto a estos verbos y veras que no concuerdan. Por ejemplo no puedes decir el cielo llueve, no es el cielo, simplemente llueve. Tambien es incorrecto decir habemos 3 personas, el sujeto seria nosotros, pero de nuevo haber es impersonal, "nosotros" no ejecutamos la accion de "haber".

Answer (score 0):

Hay = Verbo

Pan = Sustantivo

Oración Simple enunciativa impersonal

**Según la actitud del hablante la oración es enunciativa afirmativa.**

Enunciativas - Muestran la conformidad (afirmativas) o disconformidad (negativas) con lo expresado por el predicado de la oración. Ejemplos:

- Manama es fiesta (enunciativa afirmativa).
- Jorge no acudió a la cita (enunciativa negativa).

**Según la escritura interna la oración es incompleta impersonal.**

Unimembres o incompletas - Pueden ser nominales o impersonales.

Impersonales - Carecen de sujeto gramatical. Pueden ser:

- Eventuales - Se construyen el el verbo en tercera persona del plural.
- Gramatical izadas - Se construyen con los verbos ser, haber, hacer,
  bastar, sobrar (solo en tercera persona).
- Reflejas - Se construyen con la forma se y un verbo en tercera persona
  del singular.

Hay algo que no me cierra y dudo de que esta sea la respuesta correcta :)

Comment: +1 for the approach. Si, a mi no me cierra ninguno de los analisis que se me han ocurrido y que he visto hasta el momento, de ahi la pregunta! jaja

Comment: ¿Pero qué función gramatical cumple cada palabra? Que *hay* es un verbo y *pan* un sustantivo es evidente, pero esta respuesta no explica qué función cumple cada uno, y esto es lo que se pregunta.